# TabViewItem Content and Reloading issue

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui-3, winui

i have a TabViewItem with a UserControl inside it.

```
<TabViewItem>
    <local:ListViewUC x:Name="listView" Chapter="{x:Bind Chapter}"/>
</TabViewItem>
```

Each time I switch between tabs, the contents of the tab reload and the previous information is lost.
Is there a way to disable reload?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TabViewItem Content and Reloading issue

The problem is that `TabViewItem` reload cause `ListViewUC` reload animation triggered, you could disable the animation by setting `ListView.ItemContainerTransitions` with an empty TransitionCollection or remove default [`ContentThemeTransition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.contentthemetransition?view=winrt-22621).

```
<ListView x:Name="TestListView">
    <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection/>
    </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
</ListView>
```